# How many units of electricity will be consumed if we run a 1 HP Motor for 1 hour (with 75% or 50% load)?

Tags: voltage, power, current, motor

I am very new in this field and trying to understand the basics of electrical engineering. I read this [answer](https://www.quora.com/How-many-units-of-electricity-will-be-consumed-if-we-run-a-3-HP-3-phase-motors-for-24-hours) that says:

If the motor is **fully loaded**, it will provide output power of 1 HP = (1 X 0.746) kW = 0.746kW.

Electrical Input Power = (Output Power/Efficiency). Assuming 90% efficiency, Input Power = 0.746/0.9 = 0.83kW.

So, the consumed units of electricity = Power in kW X numbers of hours of operation = 0.83 units (assuming the motor is running for an hour).

Now, I want to calculate the units of electricity consumption on the basis of load. For example, how many units of electricity will be consumed if we run a 1 HP Motor for 1 hour (with 75% or 50% load; or may be with no load at all)? Can anybody help me how to calculate that value (approximate theoretical value or practical insight will also be helpful)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of general, why don't you add the specifics of your situation (as demonstrate by the no-load consumption of 280W) and someone will explain.  Do you have the power rating (nameplate) of the motor?  That would be full-load.  What type of motor is it?  AC/DC/three-phase.  The more you provide us, the better quality the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no load, the power consumed will not be zero, as the motor needs some power just to turn itself, against friction, air resistance, eddy current losses etc. Let's call the no load power 10% for this motor, as you used 90% as the full load efficiency.

The power used at 50% load could therefore be estimated at (50%+10%) of 0.83kW.

Actually I doubt a motor this small would have such a good efficiency at full load.

Comment: thanks. but, when I am measuring the power consumption (with no load) using my power meter: it is showing 280kW. Is the measured value is correct? Actually, I don't have 50% or 75% load. So, trying to understand approximately how much power it can consume.

Comment: @user1838343 If the measured power is 280 kW and you have to ask this question, I strongly recommend that you step away from the motor and find someone who is qualified to do the measurement. Otherwise you may be putting your life and the lives of other people in danger.

Comment: @Andrew Morton sorry. sorry. It is 0.28kw or 280 watt. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct.

$$Units\;used = kW\;rating \times hours \times load\;factor$$

For 5 hours at 75% load that would become

$$Units\;used = 0.83 \times 5 \times 0.75$$

Comment: thanks. but, when I am measuring the power consumption (with no load) using my power meter: it is showing 0.28kW. But, as per the above formula, it should be 0kW. Actually, I don't have 50% or 75% load. So, trying to understand approximately how much power it can consume.

Comment: 0.280 kW is a more likely reading! The motor will have internal losses caused by friction, fan air resistance, winding resistance, etc. The power factor will also change and, depending on the quality of your meter, the meter may give an erroneous reading. My answer was very basic. Neil_UK has given a more accurate calculation with the no-load power added in as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

How are you determining "50% load"? 280W / 746W = 37.5% load on the surface, but subtracting the lo-load losses, you are likely closer to 25% load. That would imply that you have a variable torque load like a pump or fan and are assuming that at 50% flow = 50% motor loading, when in fact there is a squared relationship to flow (and a cubed relationship to speed). It's called the "Affinity Law", look it up.